# Media Queries - combining AND/OR

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to create a media query which, in pseudo code, reads as the following:

```
@media min-aspect-ratio: 4/3 AND (min-width: 550px OR min-height: 550px)
```

But I cannot work out the correct syntax. So far, the closest I can think of is:

```
@media all and (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) and ((min-width: 550px), all and (min-height: 550px))
```

Since, in media queries, a logical or is the equivalent to comma separated values, hence the `min-width` or `min-height`.

Can someone assist please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
A and (B or C)
```

could be expanded as

```
(A and B) or (A and C)
```

then you could transform the expression into

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) and (min-width: 550px),  // A and B
       (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) and (min-height: 550px)  // A and C
```

the comma (`,`) is equivalent to the `or` condition

Comment: Don't forget the brackets around min-aspect-ratio.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now - and quite simple now you mention it :)